# How can you get characters without the \n?

Tags: c

In my code below I am trying to ignore new lines. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
        do
        {   
            scanf("%c",&wouldCount);
        } while(wouldCount == '\n');
```

---

**original code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char Yes = 'Y';
    char wouldCount;
    int counter;
    int start;
    int end;
    int increment;
    const END_DEFAULT = 1;
    const INCREMENT_DEFAULT = 1;
    printf("Would you like to count?");
    scanf("%c",&wouldCount);
    while(wouldCount == 'Y' || wouldCount == 'y')
    {
        printf("Please enter start number.");
        scanf("%d",&start);
        printf("Please enter a number you would like to stop at?");
        scanf("%d",&end);
        printf("Please enter a number to increment by.");
        scanf("%d",&increment);
        if(end < start)
        {
            end = start + END_DEFAULT;
        }
        if(increment <= 0)
        {
            increment = INCREMENT_DEFAULT;
        }
        for(counter = start; counter < end; counter += increment)
        {
            printf("%d\n",counter);
        }
        printf("Would you like to count?");
        do
        {   
            scanf("%c",&wouldCount);
        } while(wouldCount == '\n');
    }
return 0;       
}
```

Comment: I dont see what you mean.  Is there a need to ignore newlines?

Comment: I don't want it to exit when I press enter, while running the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could change scanf("%c",&wouldCount); to scanf("\n%c",&wouldCount); as well as forgo the do/while loop.  This will tell scanf to ignore an enter with no character entered.

see [scanf c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)